# How do you grep for a string containing a slash?

Tags: grep, slash

How should I grep for a string containing a forward slash like `./.`?

Comment: Can you maybe accept an answer to mark the question as resolved?

Comment: On Windows (Git for Windows, MinGW, etc.), forward slashes are sometimes affected by path conversion.  Prefix the grep command with `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` if needed.

Answer (score 15):

The forward slash is not a special character in grep, but may be in tools like sed, Ruby, or Perl. You probably want to escape your literal periods, though, and it does no harm to escape the slash. This should work in all cases:

```
\.\/\.
```

Answer (score 13):

You'll just need to escape the periods with a backslash. So if I have a file `foo.txt` with contents:

```
./.
foo
bar
./.
```

I can run `grep \./\. test.txt`, which should just print the two `./.` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try fgrep.
In your case `fgrep '/<string>'`