# How do I git grep for a string including a ">"?

Tags: git, bash

`git grep` seems to have simpler rules than regular GNU `grep`, which will allow you to [search for tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4262150/209139) and to [escape special characters with a backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11234858/209139). I am trying to find occurrences of the string `->upload`, and no way of escaping it seems to work.

How do I run `git grep "->upload"`?

```
$ git grep ->upload
No output; return 0
$ git grep "->upload"
error: unknown switch `>'
git grep "\-\>upload"
No output; return error
$ git grep '->upload'
error: unknown switch `>'
```

Comment: Including the error message in the question would have let folks jump directly to the problem (which doesn't actually relate to the `>`). Try `git grep -upload` -- you'll see a very similar issue.

Comment: Repeating myself again: Try `git grep '-upload'`, with no `>` -- you'll still get "unknown switch", just with a different character being the immediate point of breakage. The `>` is included in the message only because it's the first character after the leading `-` that isn't recognized as a valid option.

Comment: BTW, `git grep "->upload"` and `git grep '->upload'` are exactly the same (likewise `git grep -\>upload`), to the point that `git` has no way to distinguish which of the three it was called as; the list of C strings passed to git's `main()` function is precisely identical in each of these cases.

Comment: Including the error message is great advice, and this is one instance where git fails miserably.  In 2.14.1, this particular error generates 65 lines of error messages, only 1 of which is useful.  If your terminal has less than 65 lines, that one useful error message has scrolled off the top of the tty.  Rant off.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When doubt, use a single-character class rather than a backslash to make a single character literal inside a regex:

```
git grep -e '-[>]upload'
```

Whereas the meaning of a backslash can be different depending on the specific character and the specific regex syntax in use, `[>]` means the same thing consistently.

**That said, the most immediate issue here isn't caused by the `>` but by the leading dash, which makes the string indistinguishable from a list of options.**

The `-e` is needed not because of the `>`, but because of the `-`. Without it, `->upload` would be treated as a series of flags (`->`, `-u`, `-p`, `-l`, `-o`, `-a`, `-d`).

---

That said, you can get away without the `-e` by also moving the dash into a character class, thus making it no longer the first character on the command line:

```
git grep '[-][>]upload'
```

Comment: Also note the common solution: `git grep -- -\>upload`  Using two hyphens to indicate end of options is a common idiom.

Comment: @WilliamPursell. That's irritating, because [I already knew that](https://askubuntu.com/a/813432/652), but had forgotten it.

Comment: *nod*; I prefer to `-e` to `--` in this case because it's more explicit and expressive: It means that the next string is the pattern to match, distinguishing it from, say, a filename (the other kind of data legal after `--`).

Answer (score 10):

```
git grep -F -- '->upload'
```

Option `-F` means: use fixed strings for patterns (don't interpret pattern as a regex).

`--` separates options from arguments to avoid interpreting `->` as an option.